# VS2010 Debug Error: Cannot find the method on the object instance

Tags: .net, vb.net, debugging, plugins

Basically, I've got this plugin-based application I've used all the time in VS2008 flawlessly.

In my current project (VS2010 by the way) I wrote a plugin for the application and whenever I try to use an instance of a particular class (in an external dll) from my plugin, I get an error.

I tried watching the instance and I got the message `"Cannot find the method on the object instance."` in the watch window. **This has never happened before!**

I also found that some of the extension methods in the plugin does not work.

What could possibly be wrong?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this error by recompiling the XpressData class library in VS2010 and had the Plugin app reference the newly compiled library.

Everything now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error you were seeing: "Cannot find the method on the object instance" in debugging other application code as well and I have found that performing a "Clean" fixes the issues. It seems the debug information has somehow gotten jumbled up and out of step with the code being debugged.