# Debugging List<T>.Count throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have external class `Item` that if I make:

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
```

that hovering mouse on it during debugging shows

> 'items.Count' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'   int {System.ArgumentException}

I cannot share the whole code of this class but what might be the reason. I decompiled class and I see that there are GetHashCode and Equals method overriden. May it be a cause?

**Edit**:

In debug, after line

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
```

using Immediate window and writing there items.Count I get:

```
'items.Count' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
base {System.SystemException}: {"Cannot find the method on the object instance."}
Message: "Cannot find the method on the object instance."
ParamName: null
```

Comment: Can you post the Stack Trace?

Comment: If you try to get the count in the immediate window, do you get the same error (and a stack trace)? I don't think it shows a stack trace when you hover over while debugging.

Comment: The error is obviously not in `items.Count` as `List<T>.Count` is simply a bare getter that returns an internal field. No such exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Edited post and added results from immediate window. Stack trace is null only message: "Cannot find the method on the object instance."

Comment: @jotbek: Is it possible that you are using a namespace which causes `List<Item>` to resolve to some class other than `System.Collections.Generic.List<>`?

Comment: Possible related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229342/vs2010-debug-error-cannot-find-the-method-on-the-object-instance and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/0355718b-2ca8-40c0-9438-e3af7ee6776e/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2004/10/07/239404.aspx

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: No, actually in rest of my code I use this list iterating on it, adding new items, etc. I'am just wondering what is causing this behavior when checking it under debugging session.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: ...and that might be a solution :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at ILSpy or Reflector shows that `List<T>.Count` could not possibly raise that exception.

```
/// <summary>Gets the number of elements actually contained in the
///   <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1" />.</summary>
/// <returns>The number of elements actually contained in the
///   <see cref="T:System.Collections.Generic.List`1" />.</returns>
public int Count
{
    get { return this._size; }
}
```

Given you receive this during debugging, I believe you have a 3rd party control or plugin-in which is causing this exception. Try cleaning/rebuilding, re-adding 3rd party references, and/or running [Visual Studio in safe mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: My code is only this which creates new List<Item>. I would like to know what is causing this exception just by creating empty list. And to be exact exception is not thrown into your face in VS2010 but when hovering mouse on list variable or same when using immediate window.